# Python3 logging exclude certain modules?

Tags: python-3.x

Some modules (paramiko) I use in my code already has logging configured, which produces tons of logging messages.

What can I do to print logging messages from my code only, not from imported modules.

Logging is configured globally with logging.basicConfig()

Comment: How are you setting up the logging messages to print?  Are you using `basicConfig`?  Are you creating a logging stream handler?

Comment: Yes basicConfig() globally. no handler used.

Answer (score 2):

If you [check out the logging module source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1679), or [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) you'll see that `basicConfig` configures the root logger, which is the same logger that you get via

```
logging.getLogger('')
```

If you read through the logging docs, you'll see that `basicConfig` is exactly that - basic config. You *really* should be using something like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

You can then add a variety of handlers to your logger:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
h = logging.StreamHandler()
h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(h)
```

Now your logger will only display log messages from *your* program.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `basicConfig`.  Make sure your modules are logging to their own logger and not the root logger.

```
log = logging.getLogger('my_package')

log.debug('a message')
```

Make sure to only setup the logging handlers in a single module, generally it's done in the script you call that runs the tool.  Get the same logger that is being used in your package, then add a handler to *just* that logger.

```
log = logging.getLogger('my_package')
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(handler)
```

You should only see logging messages from the `my_package` logger now, and from any children of that logger.

A common convention is to put this at the top of every module you have that is going to use logging

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This way, the logger used for each module will just be the import path for that module.  So if you import that module by doing `import package.module`, the name of the logger will also be `"package.module"`.  That way, it's easy to specify a specific logger you want to log.